# Accessing a SWT component in one method inside another method

Tags: java, swt

I have created the method below which creates a simple help button with SWT...

```
public void HButtonInitialise() {
    Button btnH = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
    btnH.setBounds(871, 35, 51, 32);
    btnH.setText("Get More Help");

    btnH.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

        // Message box to display help message.
        MessageBox help = new MessageBox(shell, SWT.ICON_QUESTION | SWT.OK);
        help.setText("This is help");

        // Open dialog and await user selection.
        help.open();
        }
    });
}
```

However, I would like to split the actual creation of the button and the functionality of the button to make two methods like so ...

```
public void HButtonInitialise() {
    Button btnH = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
    btnH.setBounds(871, 35, 51, 32);
    btnH.setText("Get More Help");
}

public void HButtonFunctionality() {
    btnH.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {  
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {      
        // Message box to display help message.
        MessageBox help = new MessageBox(shell, SWT.ICON_QUESTION | SWT.OK);
        help.setText("This is help");

        // Open dialog and await user selection.
        help.open();
        }
    });
}
```

However, I get an error saying that `btnH cannot be resolved` and have tried calling `HButtonInitialise()` inside the `HButtonFunctionality()` method but this does not seem to work. I am not sure if there's a better way to do this. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your btnH has scope within the HButtonInitialise method hence it cannot be accessed outside the method.

```
// Your code
public void HButtonInitialise() {
    Button btnH = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE); // Local reference
    btnH.setBounds(871, 35, 51, 32);
    btnH.setText("Get More Help");
} // btnH has no meaning outside this method
```

To make it accessible, declare button btnH as member variable inside the class and initialize in HButtonInitialise method

For example,

```
class MyClass {
    private Button btnH;

    public void HButtonInitialise() {
        btnH = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE); // You are now assigning btnH which is accessible throughout the class
        // Write Rest of the code here
    }

    public void HButtonFunctionality() {
        // You can now freely access btnH here
    }
}
```

Make sure you call HButtonInitialise() before using btnH elsewhere or you will get a NullPointerException